# Unable to display raw html Data in blade file with substr function

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get first 100 characters from MySQL database. while displaying I can able to display all the characters using this

`{!! $blog->description !!}` code.

If I need to display 100 characters then it is not working

`{!! substr($blog->description,0,200) !!}`.

I tried using different ways

```
<?php $description =  substr($blog->description,0,200) ?>

 <p>  {!! $description !!} </p>
```

I am not understanding what is wrong in my code.

Comment: This should probably go into your sql-query somewhere, there's no need to fetch for example 10000 characters and then only show 100. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Comment: Ya we can do that way also. But what is wrong in my code? any syntax mistake

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Babak I am not getting any error. Characters are no displaying

Comment: maybe there are other html tags inside your ```$blog->description``` field try: ```{{ dd($description) }}``` to see what is inside

Comment: @Babak yes I am storing html tags in table. using text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this show html characters in your html but you cant substring that before rendering

you can use that code to delete special characters and substring

```
{{ substr(strip_tags($blog->description),0,200) }}
```

Comment: I tried doing this I am storing html tags in mysql table. I need to render as it is. If I used this I cannot able to render same html tags

Comment: there is no way to have both. it's better to add new field in your database for short description